# oil change indicator on after oil change 2004 colorado

Tags: scheduled-maintenance

2004 Chevrolet Colorado 5cyl. 4x4

Hello. I just changed my oil after my "change oil" indicator came on. 
New filter, new oil

However my "change oil" indicator is still showing.

Do I need to clear out the codes?

What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had to hold down the button for 10 seconds to get the oil timer to reset.  In the owners manual it should tell you how to work the computer and messages.  If this does not help call the dealership and ask how to reset the oil filter timer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to reset it. There should be a button.

I found these instructions on a forum:

1. Turn the ignition to RUN with the engine OFF.
2. Press and release the reset button in the driver information center (DIC) until the OIL LIFE message is displayed.
3. Once the alternating OIL LIFE and RESET messages appear on the DIC display, press and hold the reset stem until several beeps sound. This confirms the OIL LIFE system has been reset.
4. Turn the key to lock. If the CHANGE OIL message comes back on when you start the engine, the ENGINE OIL LIFE system has not reset. Repeat the procedure

http://coloradofans.com/forums/67-technical-questions-tips-how/72548-tip-gm-oil-life-system-how-reset-change-oil-message.html